# Valores nulos al concatenar dos DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

al concatenar mis dos DataFrame, me figuran los valores nulos, sobre el final del DataFrame, se que debo solucionar o hacer un reset_index, pero no se en que lugar ponerlo. Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad preguntas con código en formato de imagen. Esto es así porque a las personas que te queremos ayudar, el formato imagen nos hace tener que escribir todo el código para reproducir tu problema, cuando si lo pones en formato texto, no es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Por otro lado ¿Cómo quieres concatenar los dataframes? Entiendo que quieres hacer un join, porque has marcado ```axis=1``` pero por asegurar.  Por favor agrega esta información a tu pregunta